# Php and Mysql sorting data inside the table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, sorting

I am having problems in sorting the database inside my table using dropdown list I already use a couple of methods but it didnt work

heare is my php/query code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "admin_table";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // $res = array('un' => 'username',
    // 'hs' => 'highscore',
    // 'oi' => 'oil',
    // 'ml' => 'metal',
    // 'cp' => 'copper',
    // 'gd' => 'Gold', );
    $sql = " SELECT id,username,highscore,oil,metal,copper,gold FROM users";

    switch ($_POST['sort']) {
        case 'un':
            $sql .='ORDER BY username';
            break;
        case 'hs':
            $sql .='ORDER BY highscore';
            break;
        case 'oi':
            $sql .='ORDER BY oil';
            break;
        case 'ml':
            $sql .='ORDER BY metal';
            break;
        case 'cp':
            $sql .='ORDER BY copper';
            break;
        case 'gd':
            $sql .='ORDER BY gold';
            break;

    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
```

and here is my html code:

```
<div class = 'sort-table'>
<form name="sort" action="" method="POST">
    <select id="sorting" name="select">
        <option value="id"> Sort by...</option>
        <option value="username">Username</option>
        <option value="highscore">Highscore</option>
        <option value="oil">Oil</option>
        <option value="metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="copper">Copper</option>
        <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="go-sort" value="OK" id="go-sort">
</form>
```

if there are other ways please let me know thank you in advance and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You used the wrong attribute. It should be for the `<select>`, not `<form>`. Voting as a typographical error.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure this is related to MySQL after all?

Comment: theres this error code saying "sort" was not found, i cant tell if it has connection with mysql im sorry

Comment: your sql will end up like `SELECT id,username,highscore,oil,metal,copper,gold FROM usersORDER BY username`, you'll need a space before `ORDER BY`. not to mention sql injection possibilities...

Comment: ^ that also qualifies as a typographical error.

Comment: Funk Forty Niner it dint work out either I treid doing it

Comment: I already fixed them but I both of the typographical errors

Comment: You need to do @RolenzPangan as I did here with the @ symbol; I only saw your comment above because I revisited the question. Btw, did you try Pedro's answer? Seems to be the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

you are referring to the form itself, rather than the input element.

your generated SQL was malformed.

your code was susceptible to sql injection.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "admin_table";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, username, highscore, oil, metal, copper, gold FROM users";
$orders = [
   'username',
   'highscore',
   'oil',
   'metal',
   'copper',
   'gold',
];

// Refer to correct form element 'select' rather than 'sort'
// Only use a predefined option to order by
$order = in_array($_POST['select'], $orders) ? $_POST['select'] : false;

if ($order) {
   $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . $order;
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think is better this

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "admin_table";

    // Create connection

    try {

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $selected = $_POST['select'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,username,highscore,oil,metal,copper,gold FROM users ORDER BY ? ");

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $selected);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();


    } catch (Exception $e ) {
        echo "Service unavailable";
        echo "message: " . $e->message;
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: why would this be better?

Comment: You've just added a major security vulnerability into OP's code

Comment: If you add such an answer, please include some explanation: what did the OP make wrong (in your eyes), how did you fix that?